# remove column and insert numbers

Tags: bash, insert, replace

I am working in linux bash environment, and I have many files to edit, 900 or so. 
In one file,filename.txt, I have list of file names, one file name per line. 
for example

```
ab2.pdb.101
ab2.pdb.109
ab2.pdb.126
ab2.pdb.127
ab2.pdb.13
ab2.pdb.187
ab2.pdb.188
```

and the first few lines of context of these files are like,(total of 245 lines)

```
REMARK   1                     PDB file generated by ptraj (set    33)
ATOM      1  N   ALA     1      11.304   3.018  20.878  0.1414  1.8240
ATOM      2  H1  ALA     1      11.574   3.686  21.593  0.1997  0.6000
ATOM      3  H2  ALA     1      11.901   3.162  20.074  0.1997  0.6000
ATOM      4  H3  ALA     1      10.342   3.207  20.625  0.1997  0.6000
ATOM      5  CA  ALA     1      11.449   1.637  21.381  0.0962  1.9080
ATOM      6  HA  ALA     1      12.509   1.464  21.561  0.0889  1.1000
```

I would like to replace the last two columns of numers from second line to the end of file with 0.0000 0.0000

```
0.1414  1.8240
0.1997  0.6000
0.1997  0.6000
0.1997  0.6000
0.0962  1.9080
0.0889  1.1000
```

to

```
0.0000  0.0000
0.0000  0.0000
0.0000  0.0000
0.0000  0.0000
0.0000  0.0000
0.0000  0.0000
```

So I would like to read in a file which file names are in one text file named "filenames.txt" and replace last two column numbers to 0.0000.

Thank you all for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code uses `head` to get the first line, `tail` to get the rest, `cut` to get only the starting columns, `paste` to add additional columns, (these two assume tab is used to separate columns), `yes` to generate the columns.

```
#! /bin/bash
while read file ; do {
        head -n1 "$file"
        tail -n+2 "$file" | \
            cut -f1-8 | \
            paste - <( yes 0.0000$'\t'0.0000 | \
            head -n $(( $( wc -l < "$file")-1 ))
        )
    }  > "$file".new
done < filenames.txt
```

**Update:**
If the structure of the files is more complicated, I would use something more comfortable than bash. For example, this is how to do it in Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $NAMES, '<', 'filenames.txt' or die $!;
for my $file (<$NAMES>) {
    chomp $file;
    open my $FILE, '<', $file or die $!;
    open my $NEW,  '>', "$file.new" or die $!;
    print {$NEW} scalar <$FILE>;               # print 1st line
    while (<$FILE>) {
        my @fields = split /(\s+)/;            # keep separators
        @fields[-4, -2] = ('0.0000') x 2;      # replace the last two non-whitespace columns
        print {$NEW} @fields;
    }
}
```

Comment: `=n` is not a valid option to head. `read` never gets any input.

Comment: @choroba I did the script above and it removed first row of the file and it just added 0.0000's at the end of every line. it did not remove the last two column of numbers. EDIT "I think I missed one of the brackets i'll try again"

Comment: @choroba it still has the same problems.

Comment: @doyongkim: That's probably because the columns are not separated by tabs.

Comment: @choroba: any solutions? I was thinking adding colrm in the middle of the script. and having some hard time to work it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a nicer way to specify tabs between the columns but it's not coming to me:

```
#!/bin/bash

# create a list of the files to edit
declare -a FILES=(
    ab2.pdb.101
    ab2.pdb.109
    ab2.pdb.126
    ab2.pdb.127
    ab2.pdb.13
    ab2.pdb.187
    ab2.pdb.188
)

# iterate over the list
for FILE in ${FILES[@]};
do
    NEW=$FILE.new
    head -1 $FILE > $NEW
    cat $FILE | awk 'NR>1 { print $1,"\t",$2,"\t",$3,"\t",$4,"\t",$5,"\t",$6,"\t","0.000","\t","0.000" }' >> $FILE.new
done
```

Hope this helps.

Actually... I'm not sure if you wanted to retain the first line in the files as well. Let me know if you do and I'll amend this.

**EDITED**

Updated to include the header line from each file :)

Comment: `awk 'BEGIN{OFS = "\t"} NR > 1 {$9 = $10 = "0.0000"; print} "$FILE" > "$NEW"`

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. Adding this to my notes :)

Comment: Oh, `awk 'BEGIN {OFS = "\t"} NR == 1 {print} NR > 1 {$9 = $10 = "0.0000"; print} "$FILE" > "$NEW"` (instead of using `head`)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in $(cat filename.txt);
do
    perl -pi -e 's/\d+(\.\d+)?(\s+)\d+(\.\d+)?$/0.0000${2}0.0000/g' $file
done
```

Explanation of the regex:

- `$` at the end means match the end of the line
- `\d+(\.\d+)?` means match a number, with an optional decimal part
- `(\s+)` is used to "copy" the whitespace so it's preserved in the replacement

I know it isn't "pure" Bash, but I hope one call to Perl is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Funny that everyone has a solution in their language of choice.  Personally I'd use Perl too but do add some more to this mix, how about bash with sed?

```
#!/bin/bash
function fixfile() {
  #skip the 'REMARK' line and any blank lines, replace other lines
  sed '/^REMARK.*/d' $1 | sed '/^ *$/d' | sed 's/^.*/0.0000  0.0000/' > $1$$
  mv $1$$ $1
}

for fname in `cat filelist`; do
  fixfile $fname
done
```

You said "replace last two column numbers to 0.0000", but your example shows the complete replacement of these lines with the fixed "0.0000  0.0000".  Did you mean to preserve the lines and replace the last two columns, or did you actually want to replace the whole lines?